# How to add additional CSS class to React NavLink if there is a conditional CSS class exist?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this NavLink exist in a React component where a conditional class loads if button is clicked. Like here,

```js
<NavLink to='property' className={` ${({isActive}) => isActive ? "property-info-nav-active" : "property-info-nav-link"} property-info-nav-item `}>Property</NavLink>
```

I want to add additional class to the outside of this conditional inline function classes, but I found no way!

I tried this, but it is not working.

```js
<NavLink to='property' className={`${({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "property-info-nav-active" : "property-info-nav-link")} additional-class`}>property</NavLink>
```

here is my full code

```js
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom"
import "../index.css";

const LandlordLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>  
        <div className="landlord-properties-menu"> 
            <NavLink to="." end className={({isActive}) => isActive ? "landlord-nav-link-active" : "landlord-nav-link" }>Dashboard</NavLink>       
            <NavLink to="income" className={({isActive}) => isActive ? "landlord-nav-link-active" : "landlord-nav-link"}>Income</NavLink>        
            <NavLink to="properties" className={({isActive}) => isActive ? "landlord-nav-link-active" : "landlord-nav-link"}>Properties</NavLink>                 
            <NavLink to="reviews" className={({isActive}) => isActive ? "landlord-nav-link-active" : "landlord-nav-link"}>Review</NavLink>                
        </div>
        <Outlet/>
    </>
  )
}

export default LandlordLayout
```

Comment: Please clarify whether the `isActive` is a state hook. If isActive is not a state hook, create a state hook for it and set the boolean value accordingly.

Comment: No. `isActive` is not a state hook, rather it is an inline function.

Comment: this `isActive` coming from react-router?

Comment: and did you check in the devtools if the additional class is applied or not??

Comment: Just added the full code now. No `isActive` is not from the react router.

Answer (score 0):

isActive should be state.

```html
<NavLink to='property' className={`${isActive ? "property-info-nav-active" : "property-info-nav-link"} additional-class` additional-class}>property</NavLink>
```

Comment: Here `isActive` is an inline function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom function instead of the arrow function.

```js
function Nav(isActive) {
    function customeFunction(isActive ) {
        return isActive ? "property-info-nav-active" : "property-info-nav-link" + " " +"additional-class"
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className={customeFunction(isActive)}>
                property
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default Nav;
```

or you can use `Immediately Invoked Function Expression`:

```html
 <div className={((isActive) => (isActive ? "property-info-nav-active" : "property-info-nav-link" + " " + "additional-class" ) )()}>
                property
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<NavLink to='property' className='property-info-nav-item'>property</NavLink>
```

By default, an active class is added to a NavLink component when it is active so you can use CSS to style it.

```
.property-info-nav-item a.active {
     color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Join multiple classes conditionally you can implement a join function and make use of it.

Here is the function definition of classNames

```
export function classNames(...classes: any) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}
```

Example:

```
<div
className={classNames( somearray.length > 0 ? "border border-green-100 text-black-400": "", "flex items-center ")}
onClick={handleClick}
>...</div>
```

Comment: My requirement is, one css class come from inline function condition and "there should be have other css class" outside of the inline function condition. I need to add additional CSS classes.

Comment: @mhasan The code exactly does this. Please follow the examples, The first one is an inline condition `somearray.length > 0 ? "border border-green-100 text-black-400": ""` and the second one `"flex items-center "` is the default class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have an event handler, so you can do some custom actions if you needed.
i.e. change classnames
‘event.current’ google about this

For more, read this article

https://www.kindacode.com/article/react-typescript-handling-onclick-event/

Comment: Links to internal and external resources are encouraged, but add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of a vital link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Internal resources may be less likely to become unavailable, but vital information should still be kept on-site where possible.